# How to match digits and dots. It has to start with digits first

Tags: regex

For this example `hello.1.2.3.4.world` I want to match a result which gives me `1.2.3.4`. Number of digits between dots doesn't matter. As long as it follow `digit.digit` pattern

My part solution was following regular-expression `[\d.]+.[^.a-z]`, which gives me `.1.2.3.4` as result. And I strip the first dot by using trim or similar method.

Any regexp master who can tell me how to rid the first dot with one regular expression only?

Comment: You should give more details or examples. Are there only single digits or can there be more? Are there always 4?

Comment: is the expression always this `word.sd.sd.sd.sd.word`? * sd = single digit

Comment: Just [`\d+(?:\.\d+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ9kE1/1) will do. Or [`\b\d+(?:\.\d+)*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ9kE1/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:  `\.(\d(?:\.\d)*)\.\D`

**EDIT:**

`(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP1kG0/2)

Comment: Edit comes from my suggestion - why not explain it?

Comment: The explanation is given on the demo link itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your current regex you can put a lookahead at the start, and escape the literal dot when not inside a character group `(?=\d)[\d.]+\.[^.a-z]`

The lookahead `(?=\d)` will make sure the first character matched is a digit.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/gQ2kS7/1)